# Can't run deb command to install Erlang?

Tags: 18.04, apt, deb, rabbitmq, erlang

I'm trying to install RabbitMQ on Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm really new to Linux so don't really understand the installation tutorial on RabbitMQ website: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#apt

I'm trying to run `deb http://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq-erlang/debian bionic erlang-21.x`
And I get "can't find command deb", is this something I need to install? If so how?

I'm just trying to get the RabbitMQ service running so I can test a couple of things, either the tutorial is difficult too understand or I'm just stupid. Any help and explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: That's not a command to run - it's a line of text to be added to the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bintray.rabbitmq.list` file

Comment: @steeldriver yeah saw that heh. Anyways the section on this (https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#erlang-source-list-file), says "s with all 3rd party Apt (Debian) repositories, a file describing the repository must be placed under the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory. /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bintray.erlang.list is the recommended location." Aren't I supposed to add that line to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bintray.erlang.list, instead of "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bintray.rabbitmq.list"?

Comment: It really doesn't matter afaik - `apt` will read any file with a `.list` extension in the`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to install with the wrong Ubuntu version.. anyways, thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't tell you to run `deb http://...` command; that is a line that should be written to a file. You should execute this:

```
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bintray.rabbitmq.list <<EOF
## Installs the latest Erlang 22.x release.
## Change component to "erlang-21.x" to install the latest 21.x version.
## "bionic" as distribution name should work for any later Ubuntu or Debian release.
## See the release to distribution mapping table in RabbitMQ doc guides to learn more.
deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq-erlang/debian bionic erlang
deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian bionic main
EOF
```

as a 1 big (four line + comments) command.

Or alternatively, just put this content:

```
deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq-erlang/debian bionic erlang
deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian bionic main
```

in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bintray.rabbitmq.list` (you'll need to do it with root privileges), that's the same thing. This tells apt where to download your packages from.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Didn't realise that, hopefully this question can help someone in the future with the same misunderstanding